# how to recompile and build phonegap api?

Tags: android, cordova

how do i recompile and build this project into a jar file so i can use a slightly modified phonegap android api instead of the default one?

https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/tree/master/android/framework

i have edited a file within phonegap to fix a bug i have found when a status progress bar is never visible due to the fact that DriodGap sets it to hide.

any suggestions?

edit. tried to build using :

```
ant phonegap_release
```

and

```
ant phonegap_debug
```

and got this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "phonegap_debug" does not exist in the project "StandAlone".
```

i navigated into the android/framework folder and executed the command there

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to build it using the command specified [here](https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/tree/master/android)?

Comment: On a side note, it might be a good idea to share your bug fix with the community, by making a pull request :)

Comment: Yes i did and got this:BUILD FAILED
Target "phonegap_debug" does not exist in the project "StandAlone".